# ipykernel_launcher high CPU usage without jupyter notebook calculating anything

Tags: python, linux, jupyter-notebook, cpu-usage

I am using Jupyter notebooks with some specific python libraries ([AiiDA](https://www.aiida.net/)). My problem is that every time I run my notebook, the `ipykernel_launcher` process will take 100% cpu indefinitely, even after the calculation in the notebook has long finished. Here's a screenshot from htop

[image]

How could I debug what is causing this problem? Currently I have to just shut down the jupyter kernel after every time I run the notebook to avoid slowing down my computer.

Comment: It seem to me that you use linux then have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386945/limiting-certain-processes-to-cpu-linux

Comment: @ChrisGolden thanks for the comment. However, the `ipykernel_launcher` should not take any cpu when the jupyter notebook is idle! I am wondering if I can somehow figure out what is causing the cpu usage.